# 2D Cursor in UV Editor has horizontal offset proportional to how far away I am from center line when using texture as background

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm in the UV Editing work space and trying to use the 2D cursor to assist with placement and pivot points for scaling and other transformations, following a tutorial that uses a non-power-of-two and non-square image. 

If I Shift+Right click to activate moving the 2D cursor, as I move horizontally I get a horizontal offset from where my actual mouse is that is proportional to distance I am away from the center point of my 0 to 1 UV space.
Why is this offset produced when using an non-square image? There is no vertical offset, only horizontal. It pretty much makes the tool unusable. Is it trying to map from 0 to 1 space to this stretched space? And if so, why would that be default behavior?

I'm using Blender 2.81a at the moment.

*Example of 2D cursor offset in a non-square uv space.*

[image]

Comment: Oh, this is a very good observation :). No idea why this happens, but I added a gif to better illustrate it.